# Flutter assets not found in android platform specific code

Tags: android, flutter, file, pytorch, assets

i want to load a '.ptl'-Pytorch Model file in android specific code.
pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/mobilenetv3.ptl
```

So far so good ... in my android platform specific code I want to load this model with:

```
FlutterLoader loader = FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader();
loader.startInitialization(getApplicationContext());
loader.ensureInitializationComplete(getApplicationContext(), new String[] {});
String key = loader.getLookupKeyForAsset("assets/mobilenetv3.ptl");

try{
    module = LiteModuleLoader.load(key);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("myapp", "Error reading assets", e);
    finish();
}
```

But everytime I execute this i get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.dacl/files/flutter_assets/assets/mobilenetv3.ptl: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:575)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
        at com.example.dacl.MainActivity.assetFilePath(MainActivity.java:85)
        at com.example.dacl.MainActivity.configureFlutterEngine(MainActivity.java:62)
...
```

The file is included in: rootdir/assets/mobilenetv3.ptl

Does someone has a clue what I am missing?
Unfortunately the Flutter documentation isnt up to date for loading platform specific assets.

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked this? https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images#sharing-assets-with-the-underlying-platform

Comment: Yes and the PluginRegistry.Registrar is deprecated: https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/PluginRegistry.Registrar.html

Answer (score 0):

Locate your ptl file into the folder
"android/app/src/main/assets" 
(so where your java package is located in your project foleder)

and you can load the model through this code

```java
module = LiteModuleLoader.load(MainActivity().assetFilePath(getApplicationContext(), "your_model_name.ptl"))
```

```java
public static String assetFilePath(Context context, String assetName) {
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), assetName);
    if (file.exists() && file.length() > 0) {
      return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    try (InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(assetName)) {
      try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
          os.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
      }
      return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error process asset " + assetName + " to file path");
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Hopefully it helps you!